# Blue Screen of Death Chrome 2019? two screens

Tags: google-chrome, memory, bsod

I am getting a BSOD with Windows 10 while using Youtube on Chrome on one screen and playing highly resource-demanding videogames on the other.

Yesterday I think got a *System Service Exception*
Today I got a *critical process died*.
Drivers are updated.
Temperature is controlled.

I got a gtx1050ti and a gtx750 as GPU, 16gb of ram and an i7 processor. 
I thought it would be enough to handle two screens.

I don't know what could be happening, 
is this fault of my web browser?

Comment: I think you're suffering from 'over-expectation', you have a computer, not a starship, not spectacular GPUs, limited RAM, unspecified i7 which could be any one of 50 models -  but I couldn't point to anything specific except 'resource over-use'. You might be out of GPU RAM, the game might be mirroring GPU RAM into system RAM causing timeouts. You could be using OpenGL which is notorious for not being resource-sharing-friendly….

Comment: .......... okie :´(

Answer (score 0):

You can see the exact reason why it BlueScreen. Usually by default, Windows 10 has the dump file enabled. It's usually "%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP" but to double check and to verify it's turned on go to Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings >Startup and Recovery (Under Advance Tab). You can read the file and it will tell you the exact reason why it blue screen. We can assist you further with the additional details in that.

Comment: okay, I went to system and security but was unable to find system around.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the fault of my web browser?

I would argue it's a possibility. From personal experience, both Chrome and YouTube often seem to be extreme resource hogs.

While far from a perfect solution, you might want to look into playing YouTube videos through a media application instead, such as [mpv](https://mpv.io/) with [youtube-dl](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/). For that particular combination, you would grab a [copy of mpv](https://mpv.io/installation/) and then place a compiled (.exe) copy of youtube-dl in the root folder of your `mpv` directory. You could then feed `mpv` YouTube URLs to play.

As small drawbacks, video playback would still depend on the power of your rig and you wouldn't have the same suite of controls for selecting videos. But it might help the crashing issue.

---

*As side notes, `youtube-dl` downloads videos so they could technically be played locally with any media player under the right circumstances. Also, some other media players like [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) have support for streaming URLs such as YouTube, but YouTube uses a couple of different methods to deliver video, and  programs like VLC may not support those playback methods for particular video (so some URLs may work and others may not).*

---

Comment: I have all sounds being processed by just one GPU, maybe making my less busy card process sounds prevent crashes?